# Links embedded in text are not recognized by screenreader (i.e. to JAWS) in Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, text, hyperlink, accessibility

I'm working on making a Flex 3 application accessible (using JAWS 14).  After some struggles, we have it mostly working, but one thing we have not been able to figure out is how to have a link within a body of text (label, textarea, etc) and have JAWS recognize the link.

for example,

```
private function setUpLink():void
{
  var str:String = "";
  str = "my test link: My favorite search: ";
  str += "<a href='event:http://www.google.com'><FONT COLOR='#0000FF'><u>http://www.google.com</u></FONT></a>";
   linkTest.htmlText = str;
}

public function handleHyperLink(evt:TextEvent, win:String = "_blank"):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(evt.text), win);
}


<mx:Text id="linkTest" x="20" y="140" width="500" height="100%" enabled="true" link="handleHyperLink(event)"  />
```

When tested with JAWS, the entire text is read ok, but there is no indication that there is a link present, and no way to activate the link.

The real text is dynamic and at any given time may or may not contain a link, or may even have more than one, so setting up an external link button next to the text is not really feasible.

This seems like it should be a simple process.  What am I missing?

Comment: Quoting the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Text.html): "Text controls do not have backgrounds or borders and cannot take focus." Since they don't take focus, the user cannot use keyboard navigation to "click" on the links. Since they can't click the link w/the keyboard, trying to get JAWS to announce that a link is present in a `Text` component is probably not the best approach. What would be ideal would be to find a way to insert `LinkButton` components in between `Text` components, so that the text looks contiguous.